# Order statistic, probability

Tags: self-study, order-statistics

Let $X_{1},X_{2},..., X_{10}$ be i.i.d. with continued, strictly increasing distribution function $F$. Let $X_{1:10},X_{2:10},...,X_{10:10}$ be the order statistic. Let $m_{X}$ be the median of random variable with c.d.f. $F_{X}$.
Find $\mathbb{P}(X_{3:10} \le m_{X} \le X_{8:10})$.

I don't really have an idea where to start.

Comment: The probability $P(X_{8:10} > m_x)$ is the probability that exactly 3 of the variables realize above the median. What is the probability that $X_1, X_2, X_3$ realize above the median and all other variables realize below the median? What other configurations do you have to consider? Count them using basic combinatorics. Can you now write your own answer?

Comment: Ok. I see it now. Is it that I have to add $\mathbb{P}(exactly 3 are \le m_X) + \mathbb{P}(exactly 4 are \le m_X) + \mathbb{P}(exactly 5 are \le m_X) + \mathbb{P}(exactly 6 are \le m_X) + \mathbb{P}(exactly 7 are \le m_X) $  which leads me to $\frac{\binom{10}{3} + \binom{10}{4} + \binom{10}{5} + \binom{10}{6} + \binom{10}{7}}{2^{10}} = \frac{912}{1024}$. Is that correct?